# How to correct my SQL statement?

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL statement :

```
SELECT pgdd1.DT_DEPOT AS DT_LAST,pgdd.DT_DEPOT AS DT, pgdd.ETAT AS ETAT, pgtd.NOM_DOCUMENT AS NOM_DOCUMENT  
FROM pg_detachements_documents pgdd
LEFT JOIN pg_types_documents pgtd ON pgtd.ID=pgdd.ID_DOCUMENT
LEFT JOIN pg_detachements_documents pgdd1 on pgdd1.ID = pgdd.ID
WHERE pgdd.ID_DETACHEMENT = 4 
ORDER BY pgdd.ID  
DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

This one works fine, but when I try to show only the first row of DT_LAST i get an SQL Syntax error

I m trying this :

```
SELECT FIRST(pgdd1.DT_DEPOT) AS DT_LAST,pgdd.DT_DEPOT as DT, pgdd.ETAT AS ETAT, pgtd.NOM_DOCUMENT AS NOM_DOCUMENT  
FROM pg_detachements_documents pgdd
LEFT JOIN pg_types_documents pgtd ON pgtd.ID=pgdd.ID_DOCUMENT
LEFT JOIN pg_detachements_documents pgdd1 on pgdd1.ID = pgdd.ID
WHERE pgdd.ID_DETACHEMENT = 4 and pgdd1.DT_DEPOT = pgdd.DT_DEPOT
ORDER BY pgdd.ID  
DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

I tried to use a where `pgdd1.DT_DEPOT in (same first select but with limit 1)` but my SQL server says that he dont support limit in inner select.

Here is my result of first query :
[image: My first query result]

I want only first (DT_LAST value) in all rows.

My ultimate goal is to select the first group of rows of a group by elements in this case are the first 2 rows where DT is the same.

Comment: i dont use limit 2 because the length is sent dynamically by code and it varies i used 5 because is the case that needs correction

Comment: If you are going to use an aggregate function like `FIRST` you need to have a `GROUP BY` clause for it to make sense. Otherwise "First of what?"

Comment: @dan08 it hard for me to explain but assume you have used a order by (gender for exemple) in a select then you need to select only the first group (for exemple the females) how to do ?

Comment: So if several rows have a field in common, you GROUP BY that field then ORDER BY the field that you want to order by with that group, and use the FIRST aggregate function.

Comment: Or use something like this in your WHERE `WHERE pgdd.id = (SELECT <however to get the first one you want> LIMIT 1)`

Comment: @dan08 would you write your last comment as an answer because it is a solution using select